# J-Link GDB reads invalid memory between peripheral registers

Tags: debugging, gdb, segger-jlink

The SIUL2 module in the S32K3xx MCUs have very fragmented memory space. There are some valid MSCR or GPDO or similar registers, then some invalid addresses, and then further registers. In the SVD file the invalid addresses are not defined.
The problem is that the Cortex-Debug plugin in VS Code, using the J-Link GDB server attempts to read the registers in large blocks to optimize performance, and the blocks include the "gaps", the invalid addresses. Unfortunately when a read fails, the entire block is invalid.

The "CORTEX PERIPHERALS" view displays 0xffffffff for all SIUL2 registers while the "XPERIPHERALS" view displays all zeros. Registers can be read manually with the x command, either single registers or blocks of registers. If a read fails, block read stops there but all the preceding values are displayed correctly. I'm sure it could be made working, and the issue might be in Cortex-Debug.

Is it possible to instruct the server to skip the invalid addresses or not combine read operations at all? Any other idea to solve this?

A logical idea is disabling memory ranges with a J-Link script file, but there are way to many invalid addresses between valid registers. Literally thousands. Would be better to do this automatically or with a configuration option.